# Special characters can't be displayed in XSL attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL template:

```
    <meta name="description" content="{$page-description}"/>
```

and a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="page-description">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$current-page = 'home'">
            <xsl:text>Lots of umlauts äöü</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>                             
    <xsl:otherwise>
           ...
            </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

However, it seems that umlauts are not allowed in XLS attributes?

Because instead of what I really want I am getting this:

```
Lots of umlauts &#xE4;&#xF6;&#xFC;
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593326/xslt-transform-on-special-characters/1593447#1593447 can help?

Comment: one of the answers on that page suggests `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;<!--&--></xsl:text>` although I'm not sure if it can be used with the literals.

Comment: How you run this transformation (command line, .NET app, etc.) ? Do you have custom `xsl:output` setting (especially `encoding="US-ASCII"` might produce such output) or non-Unicode encoding ?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? And which `xsl:output encoding` have you set? I would expect the processor respectively output serializer to escape non-ASCII characters with character references if the stylesheet asks for `xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII"` but otherwise certainly not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can't repro this**. The following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vTest">Lots of umlauts äöü</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <meta name="description" content="{$vTest}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when run with any of the following XSLT processors**: MSXML3, MSXML4, MSXML6, Saxon 6.1.4, Saxon9.1.7,
AltovaXML (XML-SPY), .NET XslCompiledTransform, .NET XslTransform, **produces exactly the same output**:

```
<meta name="description" content="Lots of umlauts äöü"/>
```

**Possible solution**:

1. In your `<xsl:output>` instruction don't use any other value for the `encoding` attribute except `utf-8`. Try with: `<xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>`
2. In case that additional serialization (XmlWriter, TextWriter, ..., etc.) of the result is used, make sure that the encoding specified for this additional serialization is `utf-8`
3. Make sure that the tool that you are viewing the results with uses encoding `utf-8` and its default font has proper representation for the special characters (for example, the font named `Arial Unicode MS` has a proper representation for most unicode characters).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this issue was related to the content management system I was using, i.e. [Symphony](http://symphony-cms.com) (thoroughly recommended by the way!).

I solved it by changing my output method from xml to html.